# What JS/HTML5 Game Engine/Frameworks that works on Webworks Playbook OS 2.0?

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-webworks

Actually there are lots of JS/HTML 5 Game Engine/Frameworks. The lists are [here](https://gist.github.com/768272). So I just want to know what framework must I use, considering:

1. Documentation and community must be good.
2. I have been using Corona (using Lua language), and I think if the design of framework is like Corona SDK, I think it will be easy for
   me to understand.
3. Performance is optional, because the game I want to create is a simple game. Just using image/sprite and event touch.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking for is something simple with Sprites and Events you could use LimeJS. It's a very well documented, nice framework. And easy to use, as well. It uses Python and Git for its framework downloads and updating of namespaces though, but it's all well explained and easy to install.

www.limejs.com